# Insert HTML at specific position JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTMl is like this

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-1
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-2
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-3
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-4
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to insert a new HTML in between `my html-4` and `my html-3`. means the second last position.
How can I make this using JQuery?

I have done something like this

```
    $('#addmore').click(function () {
    var newData = My new HTML, I will get here
    $('.col-lg-6').append(newData);
});
```

But this insert the new HTML to the last position. I want it to be inserted at the second last position always.
Expected output

```
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-1
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-2
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-3
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-new one
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        my html-4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$('#addmore').click(function () {
    var newData = '<div>Whatever</div>';
    $('.col-lg-6').find('.form-group').last().prev().after(newData);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bf9cvjh5/)

Answer (score 5):

Given that all the elements have a common class, you could use `eq()` to place the new content at the required position by index. Try this:

```
$('#addmore').click(function () {
    var newData = '<div>FOO</div>';
    $('.col-lg-6 .form-group').eq(-1).before(newData);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4zb7wznz/)

Note that providing a negative number to `eq()` means that you want to count backwards from the end of the matched set.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
function insertAt(selector,index,newData) {
    if(index ===0) {
     $(selector).prepend(newData);        
     return;
    }
    $(selector+" > div:nth-child(" + index+ ")").after(newData);
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13qu1htp/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to add the new div at second last position.

$('#addmore').click(function(){
$('.col-lg-6 > .form-group:nth-child(3)').after($('my html-new one'));
})